# How to set CNAME to reach externel backend service?

Tags: next.js, vercel, cname, vapor

Got an error here when press Login button: https://sp-poc.com/admin

[image]

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://speechifai-poc.herokuapp.com/api/loginEmail' from origin 'https://sp-poc.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I did set up frontend service, it should point to the Heroku backend:

[image]

What do I miss more?

Backend should write the cookie:

```swift
func loginEmail(_ req: Request) throws -> Response
{
    let response = Response(status: .ok)
    let cookie = HTTPCookies.Value(string: "abcdef", isHTTPOnly: true)
    response.cookies["userId"] = cookie
    return response
}
```

these middleware setting I have now:

```swift
app.middleware.use(CORSMiddleware(configuration: .init(
    allowedOrigin: .originBased,//.originBased,
    allowedMethods: [.GET, .POST, .PUT, .OPTIONS, .DELETE, .PATCH],
    allowedHeaders: [.accept, .authorization, .contentType, .origin, .xRequestedWith, .userAgent, .accessControlAllowOrigin, .init("crossDomain")/*, .accessControlAllowCredentials, .xRequestedWith*/]
)))
```

Comment: const Layout = ({ children, Component, prop1, props2 }) => ... this props1, props2 are keys from pageProps.

Comment: or if you need you can write    <Layout {...Component} pageProps={pageProps}> and then you can use it like in code above.